# java.lang.NullPointerException at com.sun.faces.context.StateContext.startTrackViewModifications(StateContext.java:172)

Tags: jsf-2, jboss, primefaces, spring-webflow

Application got depoloyed sucessfully but when i am trying to access my first page i am getting the following exception.

jsf 2.0 
swf 2.0
primefaces 2.2.1
jboss as 7.1.1 final

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.execution.FlowExecutionException: Exception thrown in state 'startPage' of flow 'main'
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:583)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:96)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)


root cause 

org.springframework.webflow.execution.FlowExecutionException: Exception thrown in state 'startPage' of flow 'main'
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.wrap(FlowExecutionImpl.java:569)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:263)
    org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:163)
    org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
    org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController.handleRequest(FlowController.java:174)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:96)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)


root cause 

java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.sun.faces.context.StateContext.startTrackViewModifications(StateContext.java:172)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:142)
    org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowViewHandler.restoreFlowView(FlowViewHandler.java:128)
    org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowViewHandler.restoreView(FlowViewHandler.java:75)
    org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfViewFactory.getView(JsfViewFactory.java:93)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:193)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
    org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:259)
    org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:163)
    org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
    org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController.handleRequest(FlowController.java:174)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:96)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

Getting different exception when i am using jsf 2.1

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at javax.faces.context.ExternalContext.encodePartialActionURL(ExternalContext.java:1909)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.FormRenderer.encodeBegin(FormRenderer.java:170)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:820)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1777)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:594)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfView.render(JsfView.java:88)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.render(ViewState.java:282)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.refresh(ViewState.java:241)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:219)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:259)
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:163)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController.handleRequest(FlowController.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

can any one help me out on this issue ?

Comment: Can you provide information about what is your app configuration ? What version of jboss,jsf,spring etc are you trying to use ?

Comment: I see you have provided that info already. One question, how are you configuring jsf2 on jboss 7.1 ? Using the war_bundle_jsf_impl descriptor ??

Comment: yes mukul, but no one replied for that. i am using jboss as 7.1.1 jsf 2.0, springwebflow 2.0 and i have not configure war_bundle_jsf_impl_descriptor in my web.xml

Comment: First of all, to use jsf 2.0 on jboss 7.1.1 you have to remove jsf subsystem from standalone.xml and domain.xml , package your jsf 2.0 jar inside your war lib. And set WAR_BUNDLES_JSF_IMPL to TRUE in your web.xml. These kind of errors are sometimes version issues. Refer to this https://community.jboss.org/message/748452 , lets get the right config there first then we can see what error it shows and resolve that. Regards

Comment: @mukul: I didnt find any jsf subsytem in my standalone.xml and domain.xml, i have attached those, so please suggest it. thanks for your help

Comment: what you mean attached those?

Answer (score 1):

This might be a problem with Spring Webflow. I get the same exception using Spring Webflow 2.3.1 and Mojarra 2.1.13 on a Oracle Weblogic 12.

There is already a [Jira-Issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SWF-1571) for that.